# If $a_1,\ldots ,a_n >0$ and $S=a_1+\ldots + a_n <1$, then $(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\ldots (1+a_n)(1-S) < 1$

Tags: inequality

Let $a_1,\ldots ,a_n >0$ and $S=a_1+\ldots + a_n <1$.

I want to show that: 
$$(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\ldots (1+a_n)(1-S) < 1$$

So by expanding the LHS I get:
$$1+S-S+a_1\ldots a_n + a_1\ldots a_{n-1} +\ldots + a_1 a_2+\ldots$$

I want to show somehow that the LHS equals: $1-\ldots$ where $\ldots >0$, but I dont see how exactly, can anyone help with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello, I think you can prove it by induction on the number of variables, $n$.

Comment: Surely there's a nicer proof than induction, right?

Comment: Are you sure your expansion is correct? If all the $a_i$ are positive, your expression would be greater than $1$.

Comment: So, you want the *product* of the $a_i$s to be positive, not each individual $a_i$? What if $n = 2$, $a_1 = a_2 = -3$?

Comment: @TheoBendit yeah, that was a question of my student; I assume there's a mistake in the question as you noticed. In that case it should be for each $a_i$. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hint: The right hand side is the arithmetic mean of $1 + a_1, \ldots, 1 + a_n$ and $1 - S$.

Answer (score 6):

Note that $$(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\ldots(1+x_n)=1+(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n)+(x_1x_2+x_1x_3+\ldots+x_{n-1}x_n) + (x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+\ldots) + \ldots + (x_1x_2x_3\ldots x_{n-1}+\ldots)+x_1x_2\ldots x_n.$$

Now,
\begin{align*}
1&=1\\
x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_n &= S \\
x_1x_2+x_1x_3+\ldots+x_{n-1}x_n &< S^2 \\
x_1x_2x_3+x_1x_2x_4+\ldots &< S^3 \\
&\vdots \\
x_1x_2x_3\ldots x_{n-1}+\ldots &< S^{n-1}\\
x_1x_2\ldots x_n &< S^n.
\end{align*}

It follows that 
$$(1+x_1)(1+x_2)\ldots(1+x_n) < 1+S+S^2+\ldots+S^n = \frac{1-S^{n+1}}{1-S} < \frac{1}{1-S},$$
as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: use induction. One quick way of going from $n$ to $n+1$ is to differentiate w.r.t. $a_{n+1}$. You will quickly see that the derivative is negative; since the limiting value as $a_{n+1} \to 0$ is less than one by induction hypothesis the result follows.