# If $a_n \in (0,1)$, then $x_n = (1- a_1) (1- a_2)... (1- a_n)$ is convergent only when $S = \displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n < \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence

Proof that if $a_n \in (0,1)$ then a sequence of products given by
$$x_n = (1- a_1) (1- a_2)... (1- a_n)$$
is convergent to finite positive limit only when $S = \displaystyle \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} a_n < \infty$

---

I tried to apply someting similar to:

> [If $a_1,\ldots ,a_n >0$ and $S=a_1+\ldots + a_n <1$, then $(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\ldots (1+a_n)(1-S) < 1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3305481/if-a-1-ldots-a-n-0-and-s-a-1-ldots-a-n-1-then-1a-11a-2-ldots/3305519#3305519)

$$(1-a_1)(1-a_2)\ldots(1-a_n)=1-(a_1+a_2+\ldots+a_n)+(a_1a_2+a_1a_3+\ldots+a_{n-1}a_n) - (a_1a_2a_3+a_1a_2a_4+\ldots)+ \ldots$$

So:
\begin{align*}
1&=1\\
a_1+a_2+\ldots+x_n &= S \\
a_1a_2+a_1a_3+\ldots+a_{n-1}a_n &< S^2 \\
a_1a_2a_3+a_1a_2a_4+\ldots &< S^3 \\
&\vdots \\
a_1a_2a_3\ldots a_{n-1}+\ldots &< S^{n-1}\\
a_1a_2\ldots a_n &< S^n.
\end{align*}

It follows that
$$(1+a_1)(1+a_2)\ldots(1+a_n) < 1-S+S^2- \ldots $$

And I don't know what to do next but I have a feeling that this idea can be implied that case.

Comment: You should notice $$\ln(x_n)=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ln(1-a_i)$$ Also observe $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0^+} \frac{x}{\ln(1-x)}=1$$

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't switch from x's to a's (it was written with x's in the answer that I am following and that is attached to my question)

Comment: Could you show me where to apply that limit?

Comment: You want to make the product in the formula for $x_n$ into a sum and then apply limit comparison test

Comment: Oh, yeah, I think I got it. Took me sme time, but I understand it now. Turns out that this question was way easier than that one that I've attached to it. Thank you :)